# Theme based background color like scriptlab

Tags: office-js, scriptlab

[image]The background color of scriptlab sidebar changes depending on whether it's opened in Excel/Powerpoint/Word. As seen in the screenshot, it's green and orange.

I want to create a similar sidebar which will have an header with some buttons. The background color of this header should be flavour/theme based. i.e Excel/Powerpoint/Word.

Any inputs on how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Script Lab is open source, so you can see how it codes the host-relative colors. See the repo at https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose any of the below ways,

- Use [Office.Theme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.officetheme?view=word-js-preview) to determine the color.
- Use [Office.context.host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.context?view=word-js-preview#host) to determine the host and use colors based on platform.